# model die after run operation(prediction)

Tags: tensorflow

I trained model(cnn) for text classification.
so i want to test using keyboard input(what i typed) 
like below

```
while True:
    input=raw_input("input text ")
    input = funciontForencoding(input)
    print (sess.run(predict, {input_x:input}))
```

but logic die after show result value(prediction) one or two times
error stake is below,

*model take two sentence list and return result of each sentence*

> please input to test : blah blah     
>   please input to test : 
>   [[-1.73195827  1.9319526 ]
>    [-1.73195827  1.9319526 ]]
>   please input to test : 
>   please input to test : 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test_eval.py", line 213, in 
>       scores = sess.run(scores, {input_x: tdata, dropout_keep_prob:1.0})
>     File "/home/tech/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "/home/tech/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 523, in _run
>       processed_fetches = self._process_fetches(fetches)
>     File "/home/tech/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 493, in _process_fetches
>       % (subfetch, fetch, type(subfetch), str(e)))
>   TypeError: Fetch argument array([[-1.73195827,  1.9319526 ],
>          [-1.73195827,  1.9319526 ]], dtype=float32) of array([[-1.73195827,  1.9319526 ],
>          [-1.73195827,  1.9319526 ]], dtype=float32) has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.)

is there any caution or instruction should i follow? like clear session after each run operation

Comment: It seems your type of `input` does not match.

Comment: but first trying is well working. but second is not working. 
even i trained using that type of data

Comment: first try with the same input works?

Comment: yes it works. but failed in second time like above example

Comment: I tried to make new session and load model for each loop then it works.